# Curves vs Lines: A Symmetry Question

Tags: geometry, symmetry

For every line in the 2d plane, we can construct a shape with an "inside and outside" (often a circle) such that the shape is cut by the line into two symmetrical parts.

Does this property of lines extend to all curves?

My idea is if you "zoom in" on a curve, if you get small enough, it might become a line segment, then it would obviously extend. But does anybody have any ideas on a **real** proof?

**REVISION:**  Let me rephrase my question as the following:

Prove or disprove the following statement:

For any $C^1$ curve, we can construct a shape (an object with a boundary and thus a clear inside and outside) such that the smooth curve cuts the shape into two congruent pieces.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a general "curve in the 2d plane" and an "equation"?

Comment: A line would be $y=mx+b$. A curve would be anything that can be traced by a moving point.  By equation, I'm thinking something like a shape, like a circle, ellipse... anything that haas a clear "inside" and "outside," if that's clear enough. I don't have the perfect word for it.

Comment: An issue is there are strange things like [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) as well as equations such as $r=\frac12+\cos(\theta)$ (a  looped limaçon) which cross themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetrical" in case of general curves?

Comment: For every curve, does there exist a graphable shape such that the curve cuts the shape into two identical pieces? Does that sound any better? It sounds so clear in my head; sorry im having trouble articulating clearly.

Comment: "Identical" makes no sense. You probably mean "congruent."

Comment: As others are pointing out, curves are too broad of an object to make any such guarantees. You'll need to add some additional properties. First, to work with your idea of curves looking "locally like lines," you should impose something like $C^1$ curves, so that the tangent lines are well-defined and move continuously along the curve. This will also remove the possibility of space-filling curves. Self-intersections are also problematic, so you should remove those. A simpler place to start may be to ask about cutting shapes by the graph of some $C^1$ function.

Comment: This won't work for a fractal curve because it doesn't change as you zoom in. You must be more precise.

Comment: The differential equation of an oval with ode $ y y''/(1+y^{'2})=2$ has vertical tangents at y=0.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys. I'll do some more exploration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is false to say that a curve becomes a line segment if you zoom in small enough, still though the *idea* of that thought gave me an idea for a simple proof.

The symmetry that I get is *not* a reflective symmetry (as it is for a straight line cutting a circle in half), it is instead a translational symmetry. But you didn't specify the type of symmetry, so this is presumably acceptable.

Let $\Gamma$ be the given $C^1$ curve. Choose $P \in \Gamma$ with tangent line $L$. Choose a closed arc $\alpha \subset \Gamma$ that contains $P$ in its interior, and choose $\alpha$ so short that the orthogonal projection from $\alpha$ to $L$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. Let $A \subset L$ be the image of this projection.

To simplify matters, we can apply a rigid Euclidean motion to $\Gamma$ so that $A = [-T,T] \times \{0\}$ for some $T > 0$. The arc $\alpha$ then becomes the graph of some $C^1$ function $f : [-T,T] \to \mathbb R$,
$$\alpha = \{(t,f(t)) \mid t \in [-T,T]\}
$$
Now pick $\rho > 0$ and consider the region
$$R = \{(t,f(t)+r) \mid  t \in [-T,T], r \in [-\rho,\rho]\}
$$
If $\rho$ is sufficiently small, its intersection with the curve $\Gamma$ is equal to $\alpha$, and $\alpha$ cuts $R$ into two congruent pieces $R = R_- \cup R_+$ where
$$R_- = \{(t,f(t)+r) \mid t \in [-T,T], r \in [-\rho,0]\}
$$
$$R_+ = \{(t,f(t)+r) \mid  t \in [-T,T], r \in [0,\rho]\}
$$
The rigid motion $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y+\rho)$ demonstrates the translational symmetry between $R_-$ and $R_+$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll send the bounty as soon as I can.